# is there a way to exctract public gpc tracers from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

OpenStreetMap provide the users with historical data of osm user traces which are provided like [this](https://www.openstreetmap.org/traces)

i tried to search for a way to extract these data but i couldn't fine an optimal solution
can any one help me with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [GitHub](https://github.com/kengggg/osm-gpx-download) repository will help on how is the process of extract this type of data